# Why ConcurrentHashMap use 'synchronized' inside computeIfAbsent

Tags: java, synchronized, concurrenthashmap, reentrantlock

Inside 'computeIfAbsent' method of ConcurrentHashMap there is code:

```
            synchronized (r) {
                if (casTabAt(tab, i, null, r)) {
                  ...
```

Why not 'ReentrantLock' ?

Comment: What would you gain by using a ReentrantLock? You would have to maintain such a lock for each `r`, instead of relying on the intrinsic lock of `r`, for the same functionality.

Comment: Yes, ReentrantLock should be for every bucket. Why not?

Comment: Because it's way more complex than using synchronized, with no added value.